# Applying a function across 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes which use pandas read_excel. Currently im facing a challenge trying to apply a function across the 2 dataframes based on column headers and column values.

Dataframe A (bondDf) is bonds data where the first column are the indexes (also tried using multi-index headers but failed)

```
ISIN    ABCDE123    DEFGHI245   ASKDNA123   AJSNDJAKS2
Issue Date  18/01/2005  31/01/2008  15/02/2000  15/02/2007
Maturity    15/01/2010  31/01/2010  15/02/2010  15/02/2010
First Coupon Date   15/07/2005  31/07/2008  15/08/2000  15/08/2007
Cpn 3.9875  2.3375  7.15    5.225
31/12/2008  103.515625  101.875 106.609375  104.796875
30/01/2009  102.9375    101.546875  106.109375  104.28125
27/02/2009  102.546875  101.234375  105.453125  103.796875
31/03/2009  102.453125  101.296875  105.140625  103.609375
30/04/2009  102.3125    101.28125   104.796875  103.40625
```

[image]

Dataframe B (futuresDf) is futures data where similarly the first column is indexed

```
Index   FUT_DLV_DT_FIRST
31/12/2008  02/03/2009
30/01/2009  02/03/2009
27/02/2009  02/03/2009
31/03/2009  01/06/2009
30/04/2009  01/06/2009
```

[image]

Im trying to apply the function below for each bond price in bonddf (103.51, 101.875 etc)

```
def inBasket(b_issueDate, b_maturityDate, f_firstDeliveryDate, currentDate):
if b_issueDate < currentDate:

    DateDiffMonths          =   (f_firstDeliveryDate - b_maturityDate).days
    # other simple computation below
```

So far, what i tried is this:

```
bondDf.iloc[6:].apply(lambda x: inBasket(f_contract, x.loc['Issue Date'], 
                x.loc['Maturity'], futuresDf.iloc[:]['FUT_DLV_DT_FIRST'], 
                bondDf.index.values[6:]), 0))
```

Would really appreciate any help please!

Comment: Pictures are painful to work with....

Comment: let me know if this works better!

Comment: Okay, I'm not able to understand the dfBond. What are the first 5 and the last 5 rows? They seem different.

Comment: column A is the index. so column b, c d are individual bond data. For example, bond ABCDE123 has issue date (18/01/2005), maturity (15/01/2010) so on and so forth. the bottom 5 rows are ABCDE123's bond prices for each date on column A. For example, bond ABCDE123 price on 27/02/2009 is 102.546875

Comment: Okay, one more question. What is the relationship between bondDf and futuresDf?

Comment: so for each price in bonddf, i want to pass it through the function together with the equivalent row in futuresdf. the end output which im trying to get at is a dataframe of all of bonddf's prices passed through the function.

Comment: Okay I understand, and I think you need to split up bondDf into 2 separate dataframes, because otherwise this cannot be done easily.

Comment: for example, 103.51 will be passed into the function using bond ACDE123's issue date, maturity as well as the first delivery date of futuresdf FUT_DLV_DT_FIRST (02/03/2009). For bond AJSNDJAKS2, it will use its issue date, maturity but also use futuresdf FUT_DLV_DT_FIRST(02/03/2009)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you link both of your frames (obviously, by dates, but an example output would be fine to clear this), but I guess that if you want to use the dates as input, so you have to use futuresDf as input. My guess would be to use boolean indexing on BondDf such as

```
 bondDf[bondDf.index==futuresDf] and perform the assignation from there. Or use a where method.
```

But I think that you choose a bad way to represent your data in your frame, because they don't fit naturally. If the relationship was made clear in the dataframes, they could be joined/operated on easily. Here it can't be done. I can't even predict what would be the header for the rows of future predicts corresponding to the five dates to be compared with bondsDf second column.
If I had such a problem at hand, I would refactor the data to a frame per original bondsDf column, with the five rows matched to each futuresDf rows, or transpose the original dataframes and join them. Comparisons would be easier this way.

EDIT:
My take would be the following: take your df bondsDF and calculate if each date of the index (as "current date") will be inferior to "Issue Date"):

```
df
Out[53]: 
                            1           2           3           4
0                                                                
ISIN                 ABCDE123   DEFGHI245   ASKDNA123  AJSNDJAKS2
Issue Date         18/01/2005  31/01/2008  15/02/2000  15/02/2007
Maturity           15/01/2010  31/01/2010  15/02/2010  15/02/2010
First Coupon Date  15/07/2005  31/07/2008  15/08/2000  15/08/2007
Cpn                    3.9875      2.3375        7.15       5.225
31/12/2008         103.515625     101.875  106.609375  104.796875
30/01/2009           102.9375  101.546875  106.109375   104.28125
27/02/2009         102.546875  101.234375  105.453125  103.796875
31/03/2009         102.453125  101.296875  105.140625  103.609375
30/04/2009           102.3125   101.28125  104.796875   103.40625

sd=df.loc("Issue Date",:)
truth =sd.apply(lambda x: x<df.index[5:])
```

From here, you perform your computation with the other dates for all the df based on the same principle, then you assign base on truth, then you process the corresponding values by slicing the right way and doing the operation element-wise using both dataframes. Such as df.loc[5:,:] * values_df_based_on_truth *scalar...

Comment: my bonddf price rows will always be same as that of futuresdf row. the bond attributes i can split them into a separate df or as a multiindex header. would that be easier?

Comment: also. im linking them based on row index. not dates. sorry if i did not make that clear!

Comment: well your function is not clear. Some of your f_ parameters are from your futuresDF, while some aren't, and all b_ parameters are linked to bondsDf. This makes it difficult to see what happens, if someone goes after you and read your code, he will have some pain understand how you process. Again show us please a Fut_Cur_gen_ticker row for other columns, and the output that you would desire in both cases assumed by your formula; I think it will make it easier to sort it out.

Comment: sorry about that, some f_parameters were hardcoded and were not important. Have removed them together with edited the data to be clearer

Comment: Added an edit. I think using masking and indexing is the way to go.